# Running java jar file as a daemon and specify pid path

Tags: java, linux, centos, daemon

I'm running CentOS 6 and I have a jar file I'd like to execute with java and have it run in the background. I plan on executing this command from a script, and I also would like to specify the path at which the pid file is output. How can I do all this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Java Service(Commons Daemon)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html) from apache. Instead of implementing `main`, your class to execute must provide method for the service execution (`start`, `stop`, etc.)